# How to automatically increment version number from my sbt and uploaded to git

Tags: git, scala, sbt

How do I can increment project version number from my `build.sbt` file so that when you compile it automatically uploads to git?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`sbt-release`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release) plugin will do all of this for you.

If you issue the command `sbt release` from the command line, this plugin will remove the `-SNAPSHOT` suffix, tag, commit and push the changes to your repository, build, test and release the artifact, then update the version version number (adding the `-SNAPSHOT` suffix back again), committing the changes once more.

All of the above steps can be customized if necessary.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [sbt-release](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release) plugin.

**Steps**

1. Create a `plugins.sbt` file at specified location(`./project/plugins.sbt`) in your project.
2. Add the latest `addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz" % "sbt-release" % "1.0.13")` plugin in `plugins.sbt` file.
3. Add the following content in `build.sbt` file.

```
import ReleaseTransformations._

releaseVersionBump := sbtrelease.Version.Bump.Next
releaseVersionFile := baseDirectory.value / "version.sbt"

publishConfiguration := publishConfiguration.value.withOverwrite(true)
releaseIgnoreUntrackedFiles := true

releaseProcess := Seq[ReleaseStep](
  checkSnapshotDependencies,              // : ReleaseStep
  inquireVersions,                        // : ReleaseStep
  runClean,                               // : ReleaseStep
  runTest,                                // : ReleaseStep
  setReleaseVersion,                      // : ReleaseStep
  commitReleaseVersion,                   // : ReleaseStep, performs the initial git checks
  tagRelease,                             // : ReleaseStep
  publishArtifacts,                       // : ReleaseStep, checks whether `publishTo` is properly set up
  releaseStepTask(publish in Docker),     // : ReleaseStep, publish the docker image in your specified repository(e.i. Nexus)
  setNextVersion,                         // : ReleaseStep
  commitNextVersion,                      // : ReleaseStep
  pushChanges                             // : ReleaseStep, also checks that an upstream branch is properly configured
)
```

4. Create a `version.sbt` file in the project's root directory.
5. Add this `version in ThisBuild := "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"` in `version.sbt` file.
6. Finally you can run/use the following command(`sbt release` or `sbt 'release with-defaults'`)

***Note:***

- I have added `releaseStepTask(publish in Docker)` in the `ReleaseStep` to automatically build/push docker images in your specified repository(e.i. Nexus).
- So to use this `releaseStepTask(publish in Docker)` step you need to add one [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager)(`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.7.6")`) in `plugins.sbt` file.